# Mysql DB single field matching to multiple other fields

Tags: php, mysql, database, storage

Ok, so I am creating a sort of dating service and I have a DB that requires a field to match up against multiple other fields. They need to be stored, so that they can be ignored and set as maybes for later viewing. I know that setting up a comma delimited field is usually unwise, but I cannot figure out a better way to keep track of the matches while being able to categorize them into separate columns later on.

Does anyone have any better way of doing this without the comma delimited field?

Comment: but if it helps sometimes i have cheated in test by storing the list of values pipe delimited and using mysql regex like this : `select blah where afield rlike otherfields`   otherfields would contain `choice1|choice3|choicen`

Comment: so basically I would have multiple this_user_id matches to other_user_id, ignores other_user_id, maybes other_user_id? Is it faster to have 100-1000s of rows with relationships as opposed to having one with row with multiple relationships?

Comment: yes because it is easier to create, maintain and store an high-performance index on the M:M table and it keeps the width of your base-tables less variable

Comment: Well I would like to vote you up Gillyspy, but I cant from here, but thank you none the less! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about an array? You can store an array of information in a database. in php just declare it as such:
variable = array(); then you can deal with variable as an array by using for loops, variable[index#], etc. Hope this helps!